# PHP preg_replace causing preg_last_error()

Tags: php, regex

Not being great at regex I am trying to fix some code which errors on several preg_replace functions eg

```
$string = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])(on|xmlns)[^>]*>#iUu',"$1>",$string);
```

The error value is 4 if thats any use.
What would be helpful is a regex tester which shows what string format will pass the regexpression; no online regex testers do.
Because the above function is returning an error, the return string is null.
If anyone can hint what I need to change or look into appreciate.

Comment: If you enable error reporting, what is the error message?

Comment: it's not generally feasible to turn a regexp into a list of what matches it.

Comment: That error code is [`PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR`](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.constants.php)

Comment: Description: Returned by preg_last_error() if the last error was caused by malformed UTF-8 data (only when running a regex in UTF-8 mode).

Comment: So I guess there's a problem with the UTF-8 data in `$string`. I don't get any error when I try your regexp myself with an empty string.

Comment: Also it looks like you're trying to parse XML with regexes, which is something one [should generally avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @derp Mine was just [the first search engine result](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=parsing+xml+with+regexes+php+stackoverflow)

Comment: Try to remove the "u" modifier to see what happens, it is probably useless.

Comment: >Try to remove the "u" modifier
Did already. No change. If others are getting no errors could it be a server resource PHP problem eg may I need to define something else in PHP.ini eg memory_limit = 16M 
Consider that someone much more knowledgeable than I wrote the regex and its unlikely every instance of its use is failing.